# The element type "xsd:sequence" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsd:sequence>"

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"  ?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:element name="City">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <!--BUILDING ELEMENT //1 - Skyscraper-->
                    <xsd:element name="Skyscraper">
                        <!--A city can have a total of 50 skyscrapers-->
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="PrimaryMaterial"/>
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="concrete"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="steel"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="aluminium"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="glass"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="wood"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <!--SKYSCRAPER ELEMENT //1 - Height-->
                                <xsd:element name="Height" type="xsd:integer"/>

                                <!--SKYSCRAPER ELEMENT //2 - ConstructionStarted-->
                                <xsd:element name="ConstructionStarted" type="xsd:integer"/>

                                <!--SKYSCRAPER ELEMENT //3 ConstructionStopped-->
                                <xsd:element name="ConstructionStopped" type="xsd:integer"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>
```

Very confused - seems as though I did everything right?

> ERROR:
>
> The element type:
>
> "xsd:sequence" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Help would be much appreciated, it's quite hard to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a different error

> Failed to load schema.
>
> Reason : 
>   The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:simpleType' element is not supported in this context.

The issue is this line, where you have  trailing / which should not be there, as it is ended below your restriction etc. with the `</xsd:element>`

```
<xsd:element name="PrimaryMaterial"/>
```

This should be

```
<xsd:element name="PrimaryMaterial">
```

Comment: Oh okay, that was obvious. Thanks for the help, but there are also many more issues..

Comment: Then post questions about those.  Hopefully those aren't just syntax errors.